# I need multiple routes in HERE maps?

Tags: javascript, html, here-api

I have a map and I draw a route, but I need to show more routes on the same map. Does anyone have an example of how to add it?

I use this example of HERE https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/maps-js/v3.0/servicesRouting/map-with-route-from-a-to-b

Comment: Do you need to know how to calculate multiple routes or on how to show multiple routes?

Comment: Hello Joecks, only show multiples routes, because I have all the coordinates of the routes for each user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just keep adding routes to the map. In the example the function `addRouteShapeToMap` does that for you (check the HTML/JS tab for the full implementation code, line 292). Calling that function with multiple route response objects will add routes.